# Haskell - putStrLn multiple calls not printing

Tags: haskell, printing, io

Hi so I have this main method which runs a parser,

```
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  let filename = head args
  contents <- readFile filename
  let c = parse parseProgram contents
  putStrLn "------------------------------------------------"
  putStrLn "THE PROGRAM WE HAVE PARSED"
  putStrLn "------------------------------------------------"
  putStrLn (show ((fst.head) c))
  return ()
```

when I run this program the first three calls to putStrLn are not printed to the terminal, it only shows the parsed program.

any help will be appreciated, how do I get all the calls to print?

Comment: Is your command line buffered?

Comment: @Rakete1111 I am not sure, how do I figure out if it is, what does it mean for a command line to be buffered?

Comment: Well, some command lines flush the stream when they see a newline. Some don't (CMD). You'll have to flush the stream manually: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435794/putstrln-doesnt-print-to-console

Comment: Add this `hGetBuffering stdout >>= print` to your code and report back the what it prints.

Comment: it returns LineBuffering

Comment: Failing to flush the stream shouldn't discard unflushed output, though.

Comment: Comment out the `putStrLn (show ((fst.head) c))`. Does anything get printed?

Comment: There's no way we can attempt to reproduce this, because we dno't know what `parse parseProgram` is.

Comment: @Lynn When I comment out the last putStrLn the first three do get printed

Comment: Are you sure the first three lines aren’t just scrolling off your screen? :)

Comment: @chepner parseProgram returns a list of tuples of the form [(a, String)] where  the first component of the tuple is the AST generated and the second component is the unconsumed input. I have created a bunch of show instances for the AST types to produce something more readable.

Comment: @Lynn I scrolled up to check, the weird thing is that it does not print those three lines but prior to those three lines I have calls to traceM in my parser and it prints the output of those and then it completely skips those 3 lines and prints out the AST

Comment: How strange. Try `hFlush stdout` after the three lines. Does that help?

Comment: @Zubair Did you scroll all the way up to the prompt? Note that your trace messages wouldn't appear before the banner, but either directly before the parse result or intermingled with it.

Comment: What happens if you replace the last `putStrLn` with a hard-coded output like `putStrLn "parsed output"`? I'm wondering about the contents produce by parsing the file contents and ultimately the file content itself.

Comment: @Lynn adding hFlush stdout did not resolve the issue :(

Comment: @chepner When i replace it with hardcoded output, it does print, that is weird so is it do with the file, I extract the contents prior to any printing and run the contents through the parser first

Comment: And finally, what happens if you parse the contents *after* the first three `putStrLn`?

Comment: @chepner it prints everything, but the issue now is that it prints the three lines then runs through the parser printing all the trace messages and then it prints the AST

Comment: @sepp2k makes a very good point! Scroll up **past** the `traceM` lines. Things are not being printed in the order you think.

Comment: The trace lines aren't being executed until you actually force `c` to be evaluated by calling `fst . head` on `c`. They are interfering with standard output somehow.

Comment: Ahh yes, you guys are right. With the original order of statements, the banner is being printed right at the top of the prompt before the traceM messages. I am guessing the parsing is actually only happening in the `(fst.head)` call when it is actually forced to return, so I am guessing having that `fst.head` call before the put statements should resolve my issues.

Comment: This is why a *reproducible* question is essential. The root problem was your definition of `parseProgram` (I assume that's where the traces appeared).

Comment: Actually no it doesn't, for some reason it's not actually parsing (evaluating) until I call show to get back the string rep of the AST

Comment: @Zubair If you need your messages to appear in a specific order, you should not use `trace` or `traceM` to print them.

Comment: @chepner ah yes, noted next time I will take that in to account before I post a question

Comment: @sepp2k the messages that are getting printed by trace & traceM are debugging messages which are created when parsing (i wish there was a way to turn trace of). Is there a way to get the messages to be printed in a specific order, I am trying to force the expression to evaluate but i cannot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't appear possible. I created a more minimal example following as closely as possible to your code. I used Parsec because I am not sure what parsing library you are using.

Contents of `parsec-trivial.hs`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack
    --resolver lts-6.15
    --install-ghc
    runghc
    --package parsec
-}

import System.Environment
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Char

ws = many space

nat :: Parser Integer
nat = read <$> many digit

parseProgram = ws *> nat <* ws <* eof

main = do
  args <- getArgs
  let filename = head args
  contents <- readFile filename
  let c = parse parseProgram filename contents
  putStrLn "------------------------------------------------"
  putStrLn "THE PROGRAM WE HAVE PARSED"
  putStrLn "------------------------------------------------"
  putStrLn $ show c
```

Contents of `foo.b`:

```
42
```

Executing this program goes like this:

```
$ ./parsec-trivial.hs foo.b
------------------------------------------------
THE PROGRAM WE HAVE PARSED
------------------------------------------------
Right 42
```